# throw new EAbort

Tags: c#

what does "throw new EAbort();" do ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It throws an exception of the type `EAbort`. See the [MSDN reference on Exception Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx) for more details.

Note that `EAbort` is not one of the default .NET exception types, it seems to be coming from Borland's Delphi programming language class library.

Answer (score 2):

It raises an [exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160%28VS.80%29.aspx) of type `EAbort`.